# Different result between google translate website and google translate API client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I'm using the google translate API to translate text from Arabic to English and I have had a different result from translating on goolge translate web page and from translating using the API. The feature that google supports for Arabic is Arabizi detection which is available on their website but not using the API. It detects the source language as arabic but doesn't translate it to english.

here is a snapshot of the result on the google translate webpage.

[image: google translate site result]

On the other hand, calling the translate api using either the google java library or as a rest client detects the language as arabic but doesn't translate it.

---

The result using the google java client library:

Text: 3awez aro7 3ala el bait
Detected Language: ar, Confidence: 1.0

Translation from ar to English: 3awez aro7 3ala el bait

---

The json result as a rest client:

Request Body: TranslateReq [query=3awez aro7 3ala el bait, target=ar, model=null]
JSON Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "3awez aro7 3ala el bait",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "ar"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

And below is the code.

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Detection;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;
import com.tagtac.gs.util.rest.RestUtil;

public class TestGooglerTransAPI
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        boolean useGoogleClientLib = true;
        String text = "3awez aro7 3ala el bait"; // The text to translate

        if(useGoogleClientLib)
        {
            Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

            //Language Detection
            Detection detectedLang = translate.detect(text);
            System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
            System.out.printf("Detected Language: %s, Confidence: %s%n", detectedLang.getLanguage(), detectedLang.getConfidence());

            //Translation
            TranslateOption srcLang = TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(detectedLang.getLanguage());
            TranslateOption targetLang = TranslateOption.targetLanguage("en");
            Translation translation = translate.translate(text, srcLang, targetLang);

            System.out.printf("Translation from %s to English: %s%n", translation.getSourceLanguage(), translation.getTranslatedText());
        }
        else
        {
            //ReST client
            TranslateReq request = new TranslateReq();
            request.setQuery(text);
            request.setTarget("ar");
            System.out.println("Request Body: " + request);

            ResponseEntity<String> resp = 
                    RestUtil.getConfiguredRestTemplate().exchange(
                    "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate"
                    + "/v2?key=MY_API_KEY", 
                    HttpMethod.POST, 
                    new HttpEntity<TranslateReq>(request), 
                    String.class);

            System.out.printf("JSON Response:%n%s%n", resp.getBody());
        }
    }


    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    static class TranslateReq
    {
        @JsonProperty("q")
        private String query;

        private String target;
        private String model;

        public String getQuery()
        {
            return query;
        }

        public void setQuery(String query)
        {
            this.query = query;
        }

        public String getTarget()
        {
            return target;
        }

        public void setTarget(String target)
        {
            this.target = target;
        }

        public String getModel()
        {
            return model;
        }

        public void setModel(String model)
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "TranslateReq [query=" + query + ", target=" + target + ", model=" + model + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a translated answer with the google translate website because what it's actually being translated is the "Did you mean" text under your text box, which is in Arabic characters.

The "did you mean" text comes from Google's spell check API (the same one that suggests alternative searches when using Google search). When you use the translate API directly you are skipping the spell checking, and that's why you don't get a translation, Arabzizi is not a supported language/format and needs to be corrected before translation.

As you are developing in Java you probably will be interested in [adding this step to your program with the Google spelling Java API here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-spelling-java/)

If you send the request to the API encoded in Arabic it does get translated, see:

```
 POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "format": "text",
 "q": [
  "عاوز أروح على إل بيت"
 ],
 "target": "en"
}




Response

200

- Show headers -

{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "I want to go to the house",
    "detectedSourceLanguage": "ar"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply Jordi .. yes you are right, if you send arabic characters it will get translated (like your example) .. but there is a common way that arab people use to chat (specially on social media) where you write arabic using latin characters (alphanumeric english characters, like my example) .. this is called Arabizi (arabic pronunciation with english characters) .. so I used google translate since it seems to work well enough with arabizi on the google translate website, but using the API doesn't do the translation like the site (as the attached image in my post)

Comment: I think the key to this is in that "did you mean" box under where you type. That is what is actually being sent to the translation API. I'm trying to find out where those suggestions come from and how to get themwith an API call.

Comment: So I found out why you are getting different results. The "did you mean" comes from Google's spell check, which is not included when you are using the translation API, so that's why you are getting a translation with the website but not with the API. I'm gonna edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jordi .. I'll test it and update the info with results